# Django: ManyToManyField with additional Column

Tags: sql, django, sqlite, model, manytomanyfield

I am trying to create a job application-form with Django.

Basically, I created two models.

- softwareskill_model
- application_model

The admin can log into the admin-section and add new softwareskill-
entries to the database. The application_model references those
softwareskill-entries/records using a ManyToMany-Field:

```
class softwareskill_model(django.db.models.Model):
    name = django.db.models.CharField(max_length=200)

class application_model(django.db.models.Model):
    # ...
    softwareskills = django.db.models.ManyToManyField(softwareskill_model)
```

So if someone wants to apply for the job, he can select which
software-packages he uses.

Now I want the applicant to make a rating from 1-6 for each software-skill
he has selected. How do you do that?

I am using a SQLite3 database and discovered that the ManyToManyField
creates a new table to store the relationship. In my case it looks like
this:

```
| ID | application_model_id | softwareskill_model_id |
```

My assumption would be to simply add a new column so it looks like this:

```
| ID | application_model_id | softwareskill_model_id | Rating |
```

Is that possible / the best way to do it? How?

I am very new to Django, databases and web-development in general and hope
you can help me :-)!

Thank you,
Henry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[through](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) is what you need to use, e.g.

```
class softwareskill_model(django.db.models.Model):
    name = django.db.models.CharField(max_length=200)

class application_model(django.db.models.Model):
    # ...
    softwareskills = django.db.models.ManyToManyField(softwareskill_model, through="ApplicationSoftwareSkill")

class ApplicationSoftwareSkill(models.Model):
    softwareskill = models.ForeignKey(softwareskill_model)
    application = models.ForeignKey(application_model)
    # extra fields here e.g.
    rating = models.IntegerField()
```